# How can II cut simple 3d objects like cube cylindrr etc

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to cut 3d objects horizontally.

- List item

Is there any simple ways to cut an object without using slicing?

Comment: What have you tried already? Why can't you use slice?

Answer (score 2):

Unlike something like Valve Hammer Editor, the Unity editor has almost no tools for manipulating solid geometry. You're intended to do that sort of work in a modelling application such as Blender. (I have seen some assets on the Unity asset store intended to add some modelling-like features to the editor if that's of any use.)

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be very dependant on your specific game, the specific object, and what you're looking for. I'll try to go over some options and tell you what assumptions I'm making for each of them to see what makes most sense for you.

If your 3D object is a very simple one (a cube would be the simplest), and you cut it perfectly along an axis, AND there's no texture on the cube, then this is quite possible. You can spawn two new cubes, scale them to be half of the original size in the axis you need them to be cut in, and then spawn them on top of eachother.

If your object has a texture, it already becomes a lot more complicated. You'd have to fill in the blanks what the texture would look like at the point where it got cut (since that's not in the original texture). Also, on the technical side, you'd need to split the original texture into two textures, then apply those to the two new objects. The scaling would also mess with the texture, so you'd have to take that into account.

All this to say: Without a package from the asset store that implements all of this, there's unfortunately no simple way of doing this. Preparing a bunch of different options in 3D software like blender or going for a simple option like the first one I listen are the most directly achievable.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using boolean features of the ProBuilder, but I highly suggest you to use a 3D modelling software such as Blender.